# In django How can i get unchecked checkbox values.currently it returns only checked value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

models.py

```
taken = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms.py

```
taken = forms.CheckboxInput()
```

in html this field comes in a loop so when i try to fetch this in views

```
taken = request.POST.getlist('taken')
```

it only returns checked fields as 'on' here i need both 'on' and 'off'.

Comment: if there is no "on" then consider it as off..

Comment: The problem is i have some other text fields also , so in views when i fetch those details  it returns list list1=[value1,value2,value3]  list2=[on,on] here the second one is off but it doesnt comes under the list as off so while iam iterating through for loop there will be index out of range exception and i cant determine which is on/off 

Comment: show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the taken field in your forms.py should be: `taken = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput)`

Comment: Also you should not look in request.POST in this case but my_form = MyForm(request.POST) and check cleaned_data. then it should come out as a bool